# How to correctly handle errors on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exception, error-handling

I have a question about error/exception handling on the iPhone.

I've read the documentation about Exception, and it seems exceptions can be used only for exceptional situations.

Does it mean you can't use them like in java ?

for example, I'm trying to write a use case controller for my application. I've got a few examples in Java from previous projects in that language, that use exceptions in case of errors.

the question put simply is: can I follow the example I've got in Java, and "translate" it in Objective-C (and use Objective-C exceptions) or is there a better way to do that ?

here is the code I would like to make objective-c friendly:

```
public void addPerformance(Perfomance perf) {
        //do some preparation
            ...
    //execute the usecase
        executor(new AddPerformance(perf));
}

    private void executor(Usecase usecase) {

            try {
                UnitOfWorkServices.INSTANCE.bizTransactionStart();
                usecase.execute();
UnitOfWorkServices.INSTANCE.bizTransactionCommit();
            } catch (RealException re) {
                UnitOfWorkServices.INSTANCE.bizTransactionEscape();
                throw re;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                UnitOfWorkServices.INSTANCE.bizTransactionEscape();
                throw new FatalException(this.getClass().getName() + " / executor("
                        + usecase.getClass().getSimpleName() + ")", e,
                        "APPXCP_006_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION",
                        "\n\t |*| : Unexpected exception translated into FatalException");
            } finally {
                UnitOfWorkServices.INSTANCE.bizTransactionEnd();
            }
        }
```

All the exceptions are meant to be caught by the UI to display an error message.

thanks for your help,
Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, yes, you can translate your try/catch logic into a comparable construct in Objective-C and get comparable results.  Though do be careful with that `throw re;` line, as an uncaught exception on the iPhone will crash your app.

More to the point however, the standard pattern used by the iPhone SDK and other commonly used libraries is that instead of throwing exceptions, API methods that may fail for a variety of reasons return a boolean value indicating whether or not the operation was successful, and accept as a parameter a reference to an `NSError` pointer that is used in the event of an error to provide the caller with specific details about what went wrong.  So in this case, your code might translate to something more like:

```
NSError* error = nil;
[[UnitOfWorkServices sharedInstance] bizTransactionStart];
bool success = [usecase execute:&error];
if (success) {
    [[UnitOfWorkServices sharedInstance] bizTransactionCommit];
}
else if (error) {
    int code = [error code];
    [[UnitOfWorkServices sharedInstance] bizTransactionEscape];
    if (code == MY_MINOR_ERROR_CODE) {
        //do something
    }
    else if (code == MY_FATAL_ERROR_CODE) {
        //do something else
    }
    else {
        //handle unexpected error type(s)
    }
}
else {
    //operation failed with no specific error details
    [[UnitOfWorkServices sharedInstance] bizTransactionEscape];
    //handle generic error
}
[[UnitOfWorkServices sharedInstance] bizTransactionEnd];
```

Comment: Just one small thing, if the code above is called from a shared instance (the use case controller) that is called from the UI, does it work the same way ?

`NSError *error;
[[UCCServices sharedInstance] addPerformance:perf andError:&error];
if(error) {//dislay alert with error info}`

Comment: This answer is wrong on two important details;  you **cannot** translate exception heavy code into Objective-C and hope to get the same behavior **unless** that code does not call system frameworks *at all*.  Secondly, `if (error)` is *always wrong*;  once you've checked that `success` is false, `error` *must* be set (if not set, you have found a bug in the code you've called).

Comment: To amplify bbum's comment about `if(error)`: it is [guaranteed](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-SW1) that Cocoa methods which return errors indirectly will have a valid error object if the method indicates failure with its direct return value. The reverse -- that if the method indicates success, the error object will be `nil` -- is _not_ guaranteed. Therefore, it is incorrect to check `error == nil` in either case.

Comment: @bbum @Josh Caswell - None of the calls being checked for an exception is a framework call.  You might argue that these calls may use framework calls internally, but in that case nothing prevents the implementation from mapping the framework error-code into an exception.  In any case, it certainly doesn't make translation impossible.  As for `error == nil`, I again point out that it is a user function that accepts the `error` parameter, and it is free to implement whatever contract it wants.  The example code essentially checks for `if (!success && error)`, which is safe for any contract.

Comment: If you are implementing code that is not following the design patterns of the framework -- is contrary to said patterns with an interface layer in between -- you are adding unnecessary complexity and creating a potential maintenance nightmare when, say, framework calls are introduced in some unrelated refactoring in the future.

Comment: @bbum - I didn't say that it was recommended to translate framework errors into custom exception types, just that it's possible.  The point is that you **can** do it.  But that doesn't mean that you *should*.

Comment: The point, though, is that the translation isn't a translation. To be correct, you'd have to *not use Apple's APIs at all* or surround every use of such API with normal error handling code that translates back to your exception model.  I.e. infeasible to the point of inviable.  Your first paragraph implies that it is viable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use exceptions just as you would use exceptions in Java, but it is not the recomended way to do it. Translating Java to Objective-C that way works, and most people will understand your intentions. But the result will be just as bad as if you tried to translate English to German using a dictionary; the spelling is perfect, but the grammar and context is completely wrong.

Understanding the "Cocoa way" to handle errors and exceptions will help you create more robust iOS applications, and give you a better understanding of how to use the official and third party API:s.

I have written a longer blog post on the topic here: http://blog.jayway.com/2010/10/13/exceptions-and-errors-on-ios/

Lets recap the important parts:

Exceptions should only be used for programming errors, and fatal stuff that you can not recover from. For example out of bounds exception, if you called with the wrong argument the first time your app is in error, retrying 100 times will not fix your app, only keep failing. The exceptions are *exceptions* to normal workflow and there to help you fix all bugs *before* you ship the app to end users.

`NSError` instances is what you use for errors caused by the users, and stuff that your application can recover from. For example IO-errors, the user might want to re-connect to the network, try a new password, and try again. This is for errors that you can predict, and that the app or the user can do something about.

Comment: Again; you cannot translate exception heavy code to Objective-C, preserving the exceptions, and have it work correctly if there are any calls through the frameworks.   In Cocoa/iOS, exceptions thrown over framework stack frames are, by definition, undefined behavior.  It'll generally seemingly work, but that is only coincidental and may change in the future.

Comment: But when would you ever want to @catch a fatal programming error?  It seems odd to me for Apple to have added this construct to Objective-C and yet still strongly encourage everyone away from it.

Comment: @HariKaramSingh - But then Apple also implemented Garbage Collection for C, C++, and Objective-C, and even bigger task. And now it's deprecated and discouraged, with ARC being the replacement. Apple tend to quite bravely discard even their own ideas if they find better solutions.